# Quarkus CDI Bean is not injected / is null

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I have a simple quarkus backend application. I am using CDI dependency injection in many places. Normally it works fine. But in one case the dependant bean is not injected. Its null. Why?

The bean I am trying to inject is a very simple service class to load data from a MongoDB.

**userService.java**

```
@Singleton       // <= is this annotation correct? Or 
public class UserService {

    @Inject    // <= this all works fine
    MongoClient mongoClient;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "liquido.db-name")
    String dbName;

    public Optional<UserModel> getUserById(String userId) {
        // ... code to fetch user form DB ...
    }

}
```

I have another class that implements org.mongodb.bson.CollectibleCodec. It decodes values from mongoDB to POJOs.

**TeamCodec.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped     // <= is this annotation correct?
public class TeamCodec implements CollectibleCodec<TeamModel> {

    @Inject
    UserService userService;     // <=== THIS IS ALWAYS NULL???

    @Override
    public TeamModel decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        TeamModel teamModel = new TeamModel();
        reader.readStartDocument();

        userService.getUserById(...);  // <==== THIS FAILS
    }

}
```

Any hint or advice why some of my injections work, but others not?

Comment: What are the imports for `Singleton` and `ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: Where and how is `TeamCodec` instantiated? If there's a `new TeamCodec()` somewhere, that won't work.

Comment: Thank you @Ladicek for the hint. That was the solution. I didn't see that TeamCodec is created by a CodecProvider that uses `new`.